# How to graph an upside down 3d conical spiral?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I saw the on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalSpiral.html a conical spiral and noticed that it appeared to start at (0,0,0). Does anyone know how to invert this spiral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the parametric equations given:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{
  t Cos[t],
  t Sin[t],
  t
  }, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What to do if we want it to spiral downwards with time? We change the z coordinate to go in that direction.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{
  t Cos[t],
  t Sin[t],
  -t
  }, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank-you so much! Would you happen to know how to either plot a point on this graph so I can see if it is on the curve or how to be able to trace along the curve and it will tell me what my (x,y,z) position is?

Comment: @RobertDikos To get (x, y, z) for a given t all you have to do it plug t into the parametric equations. You can plot the point with `Graphics` and `Point`, but you really have to read an introductory text on *Mathematica* I think. Too much information to describe everything in the question and answer format.

Comment: I was able to get it. Thanks for your help with the spiral.

Comment: That's a nice optical illusion, the kind that keeps flipping back and forth between 2 different orientations. In one, it looks like the vertex is at (x, y, z) = (-40, 100, -70), on the rear face of the bounding box!